# Why does git paginate not work after adding merge.tool and diff.tool?

Tags: git

I use vim vimdiff in mergetool, but after adding it, git diff always opens in 
vimdiff (I want "less" with color, as before).
What did I break (cfg see below)?

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
color.diff.whitespace=red reverse
pager.diff=true
core.pager=less -MR
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.pager=less -MR
color.diff.whitespace=red reverse
merge.tool=vimdiff
mergetool.prompt=
diff.tool=vimdiff
pager.status=
pager.diff=true

$ git config --global  --list
color.diff.whitespace=red reverse
pager.diff=true
core.pager=less -MR
```

I tried just "less" and "less with parameters", etc.
After git diff, I get a vim editor with two open files (in diff mode).

Comment: If you comment out `[diff]tool` and `[merge]tool` in `.gitconfig` does `git diff` revert to `less`?

Comment: I've tried. 
$ git diff

This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld kompare gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff

Viewing (1/1): '......'

Launch 'bc' [Y/n]? y
The diff tool bc is not available as 'bcompare'
fatal: external diff died, stopping at .....

Comment: I tried to restore the previous .git configuration, but the behavior was the same.

Comment: Strange. Looks like you have a kind of alias that runs `git difftool` instead of `git diff`. Do you have `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable?

Comment: $ echo $GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF
    git-difftool--helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-diffexternal) environment variable so `git diff` calls the named program — `git-difftool--helper` in your case. Clear and unset it:

```
unset GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF
```

After that `git diff` will use its internal implementation. You can also uncomment `[diff]tool` and `[merge]tool`.

Comment: Yes! Thank! But who set it?

Comment: mmm sorry, I forgot, I use windows )

Comment: GitBash still uses `bash` which uses `.bash_profile` and `.bahrc`. `echo $GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` is bash's command. In `cmd` it should be `echo %GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF%`.